# How to put small binary files to Parquet file as metadata Map<fileName, fileContent>? Any restrictions?

Tags: hadoop, parquet

How to put several dozens of small binary files to Parquet file as **metadata** `Map<fileName, fileContent>`?

The small files are documents, pictures about 100KB in average.

We already put some short string values to parquet meta info map but are there **restrictions** on quantity of map entries, total size of map or size of individual map value? If yes, what are the restrictions? Maybe it's very unlikely to violate restrictions with my goal?

Comment: any help appreciated! not only official =)

Comment: Question: do you spect a solution in c++? java? i have a solution in c++

Comment: Great! Could you please create answer - project in Java but I'm C++ guy.

Comment: @Gerardo: you have a reply. (see above by Kaponir)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully @Gerardo can provide some specifics, but the official docs say there is no limit on element size: http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/#types states

> #### Types
>
> The types supported by the file format are intended to be as minimal
> as possible, with a focus on how the types effect on disk storage. For
> example, 16-bit ints are not explicitly supported in the storage
> format since they are covered by 32-bit ints with an efficient
> encoding. This reduces the complexity of implementing readers and
> writers for the format. The types are: - BOOLEAN: 1 bit boolean -
> INT32: 32 bit signed ints - INT64: 64 bit signed ints - INT96: 96 bit
> signed ints - FLOAT: IEEE 32-bit floating point values - DOUBLE: IEEE
> 64-bit floating point values - **BYTE_ARRAY: arbitrarily long byte
> arrays**.

(emphasis mine). There are additional [logical types](http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/#logical-types) like String, JSON and BSON, which are based upon BYTE_ARRAY. Their length should be unlimited. (by Parquet, computer memory is still a limit ;-)

Comment: Thank you - according to link you provided KeyValue is <string, string>. So, maybe binary file content should be Base64 converted.

Comment: @Kaponir: You are welcome. Using Base64 might be the way to go if you cannot use [the BINARY primitive type](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/fa8957d7939b59e8d391fa17000b34e865de015d/parquet-column/src/main/java/parquet/schema/PrimitiveType.java) directly.

Comment: To user: Could you please clarify how can I use in metadata BINARY if KeyValue is <string, string>? Maybe this is typo?

Comment: @Kaponir: The (=UTF8) string format is a logical format which sits on top of [BYTE_ARRAY](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L39). The [metadata section](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#metadata) defines the extra metadata  to be a <String, String> map, so you probably need to use base64.